# How to properly store and access encrypted values in .NET 5.0 appsettings.json file?

Tags: c#, encryption, dll, .net-5

I need to be able to store sensitive data in an appsettings.json config file for .NET 5.0 applications. I have been using RSA encryption of config files for .NET Framework apps, but I am moving to .NET 5.0 app development instead and I want a simpler way of storing/accessing secrets than the old reg_iis.exe approach.

I have tried one approach and gotten dangerously close to having it work, but perhaps there is a better way. My approach:

1. Set encrypted values in my appsettings.json file. These ecrypted values are generated via the following PowerShell script, then copied to .json file:

```
$SecureString = Read-Host "Enter the String to Encrypt" -AsSecureString

$EncryptedString = ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $SecureString

$EncryptedString
```

2. An extension method in a .NET 5.0 app to decrypt the string:

```
public static string Decrypt(this string str)
{
    int length = str.Length / 2;
    byte[] encryptedData = new byte[length];
    for (int index = 0; index < length; ++index)
    {
        encryptedData[index] = byte.Parse(str.Substring(2 * index, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    // Decrypt the byte array to Unicode byte array
    byte[] data = ProtectedData.Unprotect(encryptedData, null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);

    // Convert Unicode byte array to string
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);
}
```

3. This extension method works if it is in the application, however I will need this for many applications. So I built it into a Class Library so I can just add a single .dll reference to each application. The problem is that it relies on the `System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData` class. This thing is apparently not supported out of the box with .NET 5.0, instead it is a Platform Extension that can be included via NuGet. I have done so, and as I said, it works if its in an application directly, but as part of the class library, it does not... If I include the class library assembly reference in an application, the class library builds fine, but there is an exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

It's not deploying the ProtectedData .dll to the consuming application, and I think it should be...

So, am I doing this inherently wrong, or am I close?

Comment: Are your class library and application *both* targeting .NET 5.0? Are you referencing the class library as a project, or are you directly referencing the assembly?

Comment: @CollinDauphinee Thank you for the reply. Yes, both projects are targeting .NET 5.0. In a fit of desperation I did attempt a second library project targeting .NET Standard 2.1 and got the same results. I am attempting to just reference the .dll of the class library project, instead of referencing the full class library as a project. When I reference the whole project instead of the single .dll assembly, it works. Is this silly on my part to just want to reference the assembly? Is there an inherent benefit to doing it one way or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into missing assembly errors because you're referencing the compiled library directly. The build system doesn't know about its dependencies (i.e. ProtectedData.dll), so it doesn't include them in your output folder when you build the application.

When you instead reference the library as a project, the build system can figure out everything that the library depends on by reading the project file, and include those dependencies in the output folder.

If you really need to reference the DLL directly for some reason, you need to copy its dependencies (generally the entire output folder from building it) into your application's directory.

It's much easier to just reference it as a project, unless there's some constraint preventing it. If it's not possible, deploying and referencing it as a NuGet package is an alternative that will ensure you automatically get all of the dependencies, but that comes with its own complexity.

---

On the topic of what you're trying to do with appsettings, this isn't going to work.

The methods you're calling pass through to the winapi `CryptProtectData` and `CryptUnprotectData` methods. They use a key derived from your login credentials, so it's not possible for data encrypted on one machine to be decrypted by another machine (or even another user on the same machine).

You can read up on alternative approaches for storing sensitive information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows

Comment: Thank you for detailed response! Everything you said about the assembly errors makes sense. I'm not sure why I assumed all included assemblies in the library would be wrapped up into its DLL, It really isn't a problem for me to reference it as a project, just thought there might be a simpler way if you, say, don't have the source code of the library project, but have its DLL.

Comment: As for the encryption approach, would this approach not be especially secure if the login that will be running the task (a service account) is the only one able to decrypt the value? Obviously it would require some overhead of knowing which account will run the program, and storing the password elsewhere in a management system. I will read through the docs you shared, but aside from it being a pain to decrypt, is there another downside I am not considering? Thanks again!

Comment: Another question regarding the encryption approach you outlined: What does it take to make this function for a .NET 5.0 Console Application instead of ASP.NET Core 6.0? Is there any real difference in the security approach? Why is it that these security approaches seem to be primarily designed for web apps and not console apps? Am I being too paranoid in encrypting simple console apps? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sorry, I saw reg_iis.exe and assumed it was an ASP.NET application :) How to secure your keys really depends on where you're deploying your application to and how. If you're running the console app with the same user that is encrypting the keys, your approach is fine, but encryption is arguably not needed with proper access control (i.e. ensuring only privileged users can access the file with the key).

Comment: Thank you again for your time and insight. I do agree that access control should be the primary means of defending the secrets, but it is sadly not my call to make. A little extra safety won't hurt either.